# How can I tell if my question has been reviewed and left closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

I recently asked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405351/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-mate-and-linux-mint-mate) question, it was put on hold and asked me to reword the question. I did as such but my question has not reopened. How can I tell if it has already been reviewed and still considered off-topic? Should I delete the question in that case or should I continue to edit it further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timeline of the question will include completed review events. You can visit the timeline by noting the question id and going to `https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/<id>/timeline`. The id is the number after `questions` or `q` in the URL of the post, so here it's https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/405351/timeline, and the review you're looking for is https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/218725. Two voted to reopen, the rest to leave closed.

Personally I'd have voted to leave closed because I think distro recommendations are offtopic here and asking for CPU/RAM benchmarks is just distro recommendation in another form. The other two could possibly be answered by inspecting https://packages.ubuntu.com and http://packages.linuxmint.com, but having multiple questions in one make it too broad (you're asking to compare the OOB multimedia experience, which could plausibly be answered by the list of codecs installed, and the presence of ad/spyware, which is totally unrelated to the former).